# Placing mysql data into div which exists in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm able to display mysql data from my database by simply echoing it in a **blank div** however I'd like to display it into an **existing div style**, by that I mean the style is already set.

I'm having trouble showing the right information in the write places and I could use abit of help with fixing up my code. 
Here is the code for the html div :

```
<div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 ]" style="margin-top: 10px">
                <ul class="event-list">
                    <li>
                        <time datetime="2014-08-22">
                            <span class="day">22</span>
                            <span class="month">AUG</span>
                            <span class="year">2014</span>
                            <span class="time">ALL DAY</span>
                        </time>
                        <img alt="Steakout" src="http://www.thedramateacher.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/vcaa-2014.jpg" />
                        <div class="info">
                            <h2 class="title">Night before VCAA</h2>
                            <p class="desc">Staying.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="facebook" style="width:33%;"><a href="#facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                                <li class="twitter" style="width:34%;"><a href="#twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                                <li class="google-plus" style="width:33%;"><a href="#google-plus"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

In php I've decided to just recreate the whole div and just add the data I'd like to show into the div, it worked when I was just displaying unested divs but now that theres more it's gotten confusing.

Here is my Php code:

```
include('Specials.html');
$Category = 'Specials';
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM adsubm WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '%$Category%'");
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch()) { 

  echo "<div class ='[ col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 ] style='margin-top: 10px'>
        <ul class='event-list'>
           <div class='info'>
                   <div class='info'>
                     <h2 class='title'>".$row['ADTITLE'],
                        <time datetime>.$row['DATE'],

                         <p class='desc'> $row['DESCRIPTION']."</div></ul></div></div></h2></p>";


} 

?>
```

I've been doing it piece by piece and testing each time but this time there are errors just popping up everywhere. 
Kudos.

Comment: You have to keep all you HTML Code in double quotes " "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = $query->fetch()) { 

  echo "<div class ='[ col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 ] style='margin-top: 10px'>
        <ul class='event-list'>
           <div class='info'>
                   <div class='info'>
                     <h2 class='title'>".$row['ADTITLE'].
                        "<time datetime>".$row['DATE'].

                         "<p class='desc'>". $row['DESCRIPTION']."</div></ul></div></div></h2></p>";


}
```

some minor changes

Answer (score 2):

Place this after your MySQL query.

```
<?php
while($row = $query->fetch()) { 
?>
```

Put this where you want each row to show. You can easily place HTML around it.

```
<?php echo $row['ROWNAME']; ?>
```

Then this at the end of the document.

```
<?php
} 
?>
```